# Spring Hibernate - Saving Joke with existing Category

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've been dealing with a problem which I require your help.

@Controller
public class JokeController {

```
@Autowired
JokeRepository jokeRepository;
CategoryRepository categoryRepository;
public Category dark_humor = new Category("Dark Humor");
public Category sports_and_athletes = new Category("Sports And Athletes");

@GetMapping("/new")
public String jokeForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("joke", new Joke());
    return "jokeForm"; // jokeForm.html
}

@PostMapping("/new")
public String jokeSubmit(@ModelAttribute Joke joke) {
    //joke.setCategory(dark_humor);
    jokeRepository.save(joke);
    return "redirect:/new";
    //return "resultJoke"; // resultCategory.html
}
```

}

My entities:

*Relationship is that Category can have many Jokes, but Joke can only belong to one Category.*

**Category**
@Entity
public class Category {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

public Category() {
}

public Category(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Category{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

}

**Joke**

@Entity
public class Joke {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int joke_id;

@Column(name = "likes")
@Value("${some.key:0}")
private int likes;

@Column(name = "dislikes")
@Value("${some.key:0}")
private int dislikes;

@Column(name = "content")
@NotNull
private String content;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@NotNull
@JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
private Category category;

public Joke() {
}

public Joke(@NotNull String content, @NotNull Category category) {
    this.content = content;
    this.category = category;
}

public int getJoke_id() {
    return joke_id;
}

public void setJoke_id(int joke_id) {
    this.joke_id = joke_id;
}

public int getLikes() {
    return likes;
}

public void setLikes(int likes) {
    this.likes = likes;
}

public int getDislikes() {
    return dislikes;
}

public void setDislikes(int dislikes) {
    this.dislikes = dislikes;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}

public Category getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(Category category) {
    this.category = category;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Joke{" +
            "joke_id=" + joke_id +
            ", likes=" + likes +
            ", dislikes=" + dislikes +
            ", content='" + content + '\'' +
            ", category=" + category +
            '}';
}
```

}

My thymeleaf:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Handling Form Submission</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Form</h1>
<form action="#" th:action="@{/new}" th:object="${joke}" method="post">
    <p>Content: <input type="text" th:field="*{content}" /></p>
    <p>Category: <input type="text" th:field="*{category}" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>

*Specifically in this section:*
@PostMapping("/new")
    public String jokeSubmit(@ModelAttribute Joke joke) {
        //joke.setCategory(dark_humor);
        jokeRepository.save(joke);
        return "redirect:/new";
        //return "resultJoke"; // resultCategory.html
    }
```

I would like Hibernate to save new Joke with **existing** category. But I am not sure how I can in my form load all the **existing** categories and how to use it in my Post method to send the joke with category that I have picked explicitly in my form. I think I am missing some important aspect that I haven't picked up upon yet.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to hard code setting the category in the controller to ensure that it saves correctly. I would also reduce your cascade, in the joke class, as I would not have thought saving a joke should be able to modify properties of the category.

Once you are confidant that you can save a joke with a hard coded category, we can look to select the category in the ui. Now you won't easily be able to set the category straight into the joke object, you will find it much easier to pass a value to the controller and use that to select the category on the back end.
If you try something along the lines of

```
 <p>Category: <input type="text" name="categoryid" /></p>
```

And

```
jokeSubmit(@ModelAttribute Joke joke, @Requestparam("categoryid") String categoryid) {
```

Now this should work, although could be cleaner, you are implementing one of my little frustrations: you are using your db objects in your ui layer, ideally ORM objects should not be used as form objects, although that is it of scope for the question I would happily discuss separation of code concepts with you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, well basically I have tried hardcoding it and it works, it saves a new Joke and Category in database. The thing is that without Cascade.ALL it doesn't work, I've tried MERGE and others resolving in errors

Comment: Can you please give me an example on what do you mean by passing a value to the controller, not sure if I got it correctly

Comment: When it comes to cascading, that would be how it updates the related object, which in this case is a category. I would have thought that you should not need it at all.